# Using linq within a ForEach statement

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying use Linq with my `ForEach` statement to display the output in groups.

My code looks like this:

```
Rooms.ToList()
     .ForEach(room => room.RoomContents.ToList()
         .ForEach(roomContents => roomContents.SupportedCommands.ToList()
             .ForEach(command => Console.Write("\nThe commands for {0} are: {1} ", roomContents.Name, command))));          

Console.ReadLine();
```

Current Output:

```
The command for Tap are Use
The command for Key are Drop
The command for Key are Get
The command for Key are Use
The command for Bucket are Drop
The command for Bucket are Get
The command for Bucket are Use
```

My aim is to display the output in a more friendly way, i.e. grouping the commands based on room content. I would like the output to display something like this.

Desired Output:

```
The commands for Tap 
Use
The commands for Key 
Drop
Get
Use
The commands for Bucket
Drop
Get
Use
```

Comment: If you have to use `.ToList()` to use `.ForEach()`, then you shouldn't be using `.ForEach()`. There is a perfectly good `foreach` keyword. And in general `.ForEach()` is a little frowned upon. It is something of a previous era (pre-LINQ). Classical link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be much cleaner with traditional `foreach` loops:

```
foreach(var room in Rooms)
{
    foreach(var roomContents in room.RoomContents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The commands for {0} are:",roomContents.Name);
        foreach(command in roomContents.SupportedCommands)
            Console.WriteLine(command);
    }
}
```

or *slightly* simplified:

```
foreach(var roomContents in Rooms.SelectMany(room => room.RoomContents))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The commands for {0} are:",roomContents.Name);
    foreach(command in roomContents.SupportedCommands)
        Console.WriteLine(command);
}
```

You could also flatten and group the entire collection of contents in all rooms.

other benefits:

- You can debug `foreach` loops much more easily than an embedded lambda.
- You don't need to call `ToList` on each collection in order to access the `ForEach` method (it's intentionally not a Linq extension method)

Answer (score 6):

```
Rooms
    .ForEach(room => room.RoomContents.ForEach(roomContents => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The commands for {0}",roomContents.Name);
        roomContents.SupportedCommands.ForEach(command => 
           Console.Writeline("{0}",command))
    }));          
Console.ReadLine();
```

Although, this isn't a really good use of LINQ.  I'd just use loops myself.

```
foreach(var room in Rooms)
{
  foreach(var roomContents in room.RoomContents)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("The commands for {0}",roomContents.Name);
    foreach(var command in roomContents.SupportedCommands)
    {
      Console.Writeline(command);
    }
  }
}
```

A third possibility is to use Aggregates to build the result, but again, it's not a very good use of LINQ.

Comment: This isn't a really good use of LINQ? It's not *any* use of LINQ.

Comment: You are technically correct, the default implementation of LINQ doesn't include `ForEach`, although there are many extensions that do implement it (rx, MoreLinq, PLINQ -- although it's called ForAll).  The one he was using was just a method on the list object.